# Fatal error: Call to undefined function wpsc_cart_item_count()

Tags: php, themes, errors

-- I've just done a fresh install of Wordpress 3.4

-- I've downloaded and uploaded this new free eCommerce wordpress theme suggested by smashing magazine.

{ http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/19/free-e-commerce-wordpress-theme-balita/ }

-- And I get this giant error on the homepage:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function wpsc_cart_item_count() in /home/content/97/8209697/html/websitename/wp/wp-content/themes/balita/header.php on line 78
```

Line 78 reads:

```
<div class="totalItem totalitems"><?php printf( _n('%d item', '%d items', wpsc_cart_item_count(), 'tokokoo'), wpsc_cart_item_count() ); ?></div>
```

*Live Site at (http://tinyurl.com/cdva5aw)*

**Any pointers?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you followed the install instructions with that theme, one of the steps was to add the WP e-Commerce plugin and activate it. `wpsc_cart_item_count` is a function of that plugin, so it is likely not currently activated.